# Private Messaging with Twilio IP Messaging

Tags: javascript, twilio

Communication in Twilio IP Messaging is based on channels. I mastered authentication, I implemented communication via public channels, and now I want to implement private communication between two users, how should I approach it?
I think that I have to create a private channel

```
messagingClient.createChannel({
    uniqueName: 'secret',
    friendlyName: 'Private Chat Channel',
    isPrivate: true
}).then(function(channel) {
    console.log('Created private channel:');
    console.log(channel);
});
```

Private channel means that it's just hidden from others, but how to forcefully restrict users from joining the channel making it more secure?

Comment: i feel like i remember twilio having a tutorial about how to do this..

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/php/laravel

Comment: @Pamblam thank you for the link, two-factor authentication is definitely useful. My question is a bit different though, I want to restrict access to channels for already authenticated users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Firstly, [according to the latest documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/channels), if you want to set the channel to be private you need to do so by setting its `Type` to `private`.

```
messagingClient.createChannel({
    uniqueName: 'secret',
    friendlyName: 'Private Chat Channel',
    type: 'private'
}).then(function(channel) {
    console.log('Created private channel:');
    console.log(channel);
});
```

Then, when you have made a channel private, other users are only able to join that channel by invitation. That is a restriction that is controlled within the API, so as long as you have set the channel to be private, you do not need to worry about the rest of it.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: philnash, though i now it is slightly out of context, currently if i want to restrict creation of private channels, are web-hooks my only solution?

Comment: Currently yes, you will need to use the [pre event webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks#pre-callbacks) if you want to block users only from creating private channels. If you wanted to stop them creating any channels, you could [create a role](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/permissions) that doesn't have the Create Channel permission.

Comment: I'm using IPM service with webhooks and added the TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN in the environment but `twilio.webhook()` gives me 403. is there some option i need to flip. debugger shows `status:50056` for `joinChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change
`isPrivate: true`

to
`type: 'private'`

Also you could have authenticator functions, like, `if (user.username === 'donald'){ } etc.`